# How can I set template for just one form field?

Tags: magento-1.9, template, forms

I have a form with 2 select fields. I am trying to set up a template just for the last one. How can I do? I've tried with `'template' => 'path/to/template.phtml'` and `'after_element_html'` => (but i don't know how can I set template jut for this).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using renderer.

```
$field = $fieldset->addField('custom_template', 'text', array(
    'name'      => 'custom_template',
));

$field->setRenderer($this->getLayout()->createBlock('vendorname/adminhtml_list_render_template'));
```

So now create app/code/community/Vendor/Module/Block/Adminhtml/List/Render/Template.php

```
class Vendor_Module_Block_Adminhtml_List_Render_Template extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Abstract implements Varien_Data_Form_Element_Renderer_Interface
{

    public function render(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract $element) 
    {
        $html1 = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('custom_template.phtml')->toHtml();
        $html = array();
        $html[] ='<tr>';
        $html[] = '<td class="label"><label> </label></td>';
        $html[] = "<td class=\"value\">$html1</td></tr>";
        return implode('', $html);
    }
}
```

Comment: It works! Thx. I don't know why I didn't think about that earlier:D